# Laravel broadcasting / WebSockets: Only connect users who are logged in

Tags: laravel, websocket, broadcasting

I set up [Laravel WebSockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/). My site only provides live / WebSockets functionality for users who are logged in. So there is no need to connect guests to my WebSockets server too. How can I prevent guests from connecting?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you use SocketIO, Laravel Echo, and Laravel Echo Server.

Get a user access token, store it in a cookie or web storage (localStorage or sessionStorage) and inject it while instantiating Laravel echo:

```
let Echo = require('laravel-echo')

window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: window.location.hostname + ':3434'
        auth: {
            headers: {
                 Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AUTH_TOKEN,
            },
        },
    });
```

Here are the links for your needs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites
https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server

Comment: Why would I use this combination instead of Laravel WebSockets? I already have everything setup and working.